# In Postgres pass a variable as a WHERE

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, I have data that represents players. I have a view that contains each player's rank (in terms of points), their name, their score and a unique ID. I need to have a statement that returns the following:

- return the top three scores for a bunch of players
- return the three scores above the current player's
- return the current player's score
- return the three scores below the current player's

I can do that:

```
  (SELECT rank, score, name, id FROM base_lederboard
    ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION
  (SELECT rank, score, name, id FROM base_lederboard
    WHERE rank BETWEEN
       (SELECT rank FROM base_lederboard WHERE id = '123466') - 3
    AND
       (SELECT rank FROM base_lederboard WHERE id = '123466') + 3)
ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

Now here's the problem: I need to do this for any `id` value. But the way I need to pass the value is by a `WHERE` statement. That's mostly because another service will be calling the data using [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest).

Basically I need to call this as:

```
SELECT * FROM the_solution WHERE id = 'the_given_id';
```

So what I *think* I need is this: a new view that lists all the scores and, for each score, joins the previous data. Then, only call one value for this new table at a time, therefore getting the query above for any give player. But, even after a couple hours of trying, I can't do that.

I tried creating a Postgres rule, I tried an `INSTEAD OF` view (they don't work on `SELECT` statements), I tried many things.

Am I trying to do the Wrong Thing? If so, what should I do?

The easiest solution would be to ask the people using the service to make more than one query. But that just seems very wrong. OR to use an external language to assemble the query for me, but that seems even more wrong. Surely Postgres must offer a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got partway there:

```
SELECT
    bl.id AS input, scores.rank, scores.score, scores.name, scores.id
  FROM base_lederboard AS bl
    RIGHT JOIN base_lederboard AS scores ON (
      scores.rank BETWEEN
        (SELECT rank FROM base_lederboard AS tbl WHERE bl.id = tbl.id LIMIT 1) - 3
      AND
        (SELECT rank FROM base_lederboard AS tbl WHERE bl.id = tbl.id LIMIT 1) + 3)
  ORDER BY bl.rank, scores.rank ASC;
```

This will return the selected user's score with the surrounding scores. But the top scores will still have to be queried separately.

-- EDIT --

From this, it was actually pretty simple:

```
SELECT
    bl.id AS input, scores.rank, scores.score, scores.name, scores.id
  FROM base_lederboard AS bl
    RIGHT JOIN base_lederboard AS scores ON (
      scores.rank BETWEEN 1 AND 3 OR
      scores.rank BETWEEN
        (SELECT rank FROM base_lederboard AS tbl WHERE bl.id = tbl.id LIMIT 1) - 3
      AND
        (SELECT rank FROM base_lederboard AS tbl WHERE bl.id = tbl.id LIMIT 1) + 3)
  ORDER BY bl.rank, scores.rank ASC;
```

And that's everything!